# How Dynamo DB manages Many to Many relationship?

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have 2 tables `User` and `Activity` with a **Many to Many** relationship:

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
    id: ID!
    activities: [Activity] @manyToMany(relationName: "UserActivity")
}

type Activity @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
    id: ID!
    users: [User] @manyToMany(relationName: "UserActivity")
}
```

From Dynamo DB how should I add my JSON data to connect these 2 tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship `@manyToMany`, as documented [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#configure-a-secondary-index), is completely different from all others, it configures a "join table" between two models.

Basically, after `push` your new GraphQL schema, in Dynamo DB you'll find a new table:

```
type UserActivity {
  id: ID!
  userID: ID!
  activityID: ID!
  user: User!
  activity: Activity!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime!
}
```

Here you have to provide 2 different `ID` (`userID` and `activityID`) every time you want to `join` these 2 tables.

So you don't have to add `IDs` to single tables (`User`, `Activity`) but only to the joined table (`UserActivity`)